# React: Assigning an initial state from a variable, causes variable value to be mutated when performing setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

For eg:

```
const initialState = {
a=4
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState
}
```

and somewhere below in the code,

```
this.setState({a:9});
```

now, whenever this component loads, it always retains the previous value i.e. 9 as its initial state and does not revert back to a=4. Am I doing this wrong? How can I not mutate my original variable?

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: You have used `const initialState`  here, use `let initialState` instead of const.

Comment: nope, logging initialState shows 9 after executing this.setstate

Comment: const initialState = {
a:4
} 

that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

there is syntax error first: it should be like this

```
const initialState = {
a: 4
}
```

if you don't want to mutate the `initialState`, then you need to create a copy of `initialState` object.
if you use es6, you can just use [spread operator](http://lucybain.com/blog/2018/js-es6-spread-operator/)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...initialState}
}
```

if es6 is not used, then you can just use object.assign

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = Object.assign({}, initialState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to undertake that state of an application is the driving entity of the application. Most important when are you executing the setState call? your setState call should be called based on certain event you expect on the application. State of an application should be changed or updated based on certain behaviour. Change the state on click event and try ,you will get the expected behaviour.e.g

```
     class Demo extends React.Component{
     constructor (props){
     super(props);
     this.state={
      a:4
     }
   }
   render(){
   return (){
   <div>
  <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
  {this.state.a}
   </div>
  }

 handleClick(){
  this.setState({a:9});
 }
}
```

Use this component to render and check the state. Make sure you are not calling setState inside componentDidMount method.